# UPDATE using WITH CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, common-table-expression

I saw some close answers to this but I cannot fit any of them into my scenario.

I have the following in pl/sql (oracle 11g): 
(edit:  I cleaned up the sql a bit to make it right)

```
  WITH t AS
(
  SELECT  case_nbr, 
          type_cd, 
          subtype_cd, 
          class_nbr,
          case_dt,
          SUM(fhits) fhits_sum, 
          COUNT(fhits) hit_count
    FROM  DDEL.MYCASE 
    GROUP BY case_nbr, 
             type_cd, 
             subtype_cd, 
             class_nbr, 
             case_dt            
   )
   SELECT ROUND(mc.fhits/t.fhits_sum * mc.qty ) new_qty , t.*, mc.fhits, mc.qty
   FROM t 
   JOIN   DDEL.MYCASE mc
     ON t.case_nbr = mc.case_nbr
     AND t.type_cd = mc.type_cd 
     AND t.subtype_cd =  mc.subtype_cd
     AND t.class_nbr = mc.class_nbr
     AND t.case_dt = mc.case_dt
   WHERE t.fhits_sum > 1000
   AND t.hit_count > 1
);
```

The results give me (I just numbered the irrelevant columns to make it fit better):

```
new_qty  1  2   3  4  5             6   fhits  qty
57  10  E   S  8  01-DEC-15 133 2   999 77
20  10  E   S  8  01-DEC-15 133 2   934 77
```

This works find...but, what I want to do is update the results of this query...two records in this case.  I want to modify the mc.qty column (where you see the 77's) with the new_qty (where you see the 57 and 20).

Im having trouble getting an update to work with the WITH Clause and with this result set.  Im thinking I have to do something more complex but was hoping someone could see an easy way to add an UPDATE here.  Keep in mind that the query is looking for a set of distinct records,  in a table with a lot of data, that match more than once and that meet the criteria of, together, having a sum of the fhits column more than the 1000 value...only then do I want to do this.

I have just been looking at this too long over the last day and a half and am missing something obvious.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why are you using LEFT OUTER JOIN to combine rows from `MYCASE mc` and a result of the aggregation from `t` ?
This implies that there could be a combination of values `case_nbr, type_cd, subtype_cd, class_nbr, case_dt`in `t` that doesn't exist in `MYCASE mc` ... but since these values come from `MYCASE` table, then this is frankly impossible, unless some of these column can contain (and contain) NULL values.
But in the latter case (join columns can contain NULL), a join condition in your query is flawed, because doesn't consider NULLs.
In such a case the join condition must contain something like: `... AND (t.colX = m.colX OR t.colX IS NULL AND m.colX IS NULL) ...` instead of simple `AND t.colX = m.colX`.

---

Anyway, we are going to update qty column with new values.
Assumming that all columns involved in a join condition cannot contain NULLs, then your query could be rewiriteen using straight join in this way:

```
  SELECT mc.qty,
         ROUND(mc.qty * mc.fhits/t.fhits_sum) new_qty 
  FROM (
      SELECT case_nbr, type_cd, subtype_cd, class_nbr, case_dt,
             SUM(fhits) fhits_sum, COUNT(fhits) hit_count
      FROM MYCASE 
      GROUP BY case_nbr, type_cd, subtype_cd, class_nbr, case_dt
  ) t
  JOIN MYCASE mc ON (
     mc.case_nbr = t.case_nbr AND mc.type_cd = t.type_cd
     AND mc.subtype_cd = t.subtype_cd AND mc.class_nbr = t.class_nbr
     AND mc.case_dt = t.case_dt
  )
  WHERE t.fhits_sum > 1000
   AND t.hit_count > 1
```

The above query gives just two columns: `qty` that comes from `MYCASE` table, and `new_qty` that is a new value which `qty` must be updated with.
All what you need is to update an inline view created using the above query:

```
UPDATE (  the_above_query_as_inline_view )
SET qty = new_qty;
```

that is:

```
UPDATE (
      SELECT mc.qty,
             ROUND(mc.qty * mc.fhits/t.fhits_sum) new_qty 
      FROM (
          SELECT case_nbr, type_cd, subtype_cd, class_nbr, case_dt,
                 SUM(fhits) fhits_sum, COUNT(fhits) hit_count
          FROM MYCASE 
          GROUP BY case_nbr, type_cd, subtype_cd, class_nbr, case_dt
      ) t
      JOIN MYCASE mc ON (
         mc.case_nbr = t.case_nbr AND mc.type_cd = t.type_cd
         AND mc.subtype_cd = t.subtype_cd AND mc.class_nbr = t.class_nbr
         AND mc.case_dt = t.case_dt
      )
      WHERE t.fhits_sum > 1000
       AND t.hit_count > 1
)
SET qty = new_qty;
```

---

Additional remark: a `DISTINCT` clause in your first subquery is redundant:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT case_nbr, 
                  type_cd, 
                  subtype_cd, 
                  class_nbr,
                  case_dt,
                  SUM(fhits) fhits_sum, 
                  COUNT(fhits) hit_count
    FROM  DDEL.MYCASE 
    GROUP BY case_nbr, 
             type_cd, 
             subtype_cd, 
             class_nbr, 
             case_dt
```

If `GROUB BY` and aggregation is used, then a result is always unique, there is no need to add `DISTINCT`.
This query: `SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d FROM table` is eqivalent to:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d
FROM table
GROUP BY a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well.  As for the Distinct and Outer Join, you are right...its from swapping my code around multiple times trying to get it to work with an update. I should have cleaned it up before posting. I corrected it above for others in case someone wants to use whats there

Answer (score -1):

MERGE command will be the correct answer.
That will also be the best practice.